# C++ DirectX CreateVertexShader COM error

Tags: c++, directx

When i try to create my shader with CreateVertexShader(), I get COM error 'The paremeter is incorrect.'.

```
struct ShaderData
{
    LPVOID ShaderCode;
    size_t ShaderSize;
};
```

This function works but it leaks. When delete[] buffer is uncommented I get the error.

```
Shader::ShaderData Shader::LoadShader(const std::string& file)
{
    std::ifstream ifs(file, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    if (!ifs) return;

    ifs.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    size_t size = static_cast<std::size_t>(ifs.tellg());
    ifs.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    char* buffer = new char[size];
    ifs.read(buffer, len);

    ShaderData data = { buffer, size };
    //delete[] buffer;

   return data;
}
```

Another version of the same function but using std::vector, I still get the same error.

```
Shader::ShaderData Shader::LoadShader(const std::string& file)
{
    std::ifstream ifs(file, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    if (!ifs) return;

    ifs.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    size_t size = static_cast<std::size_t>(ifs.tellg());
    ifs.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    std::vector<char> buffer(size);

    ifs.read(buffer.data(), size);

    ShaderData data = { static_cast<void*>(buffer.data()), size };

    return data;
}
```

Function creating the shaders. m_vertex_data and m_pixel_data are both member variables of class Shader, and holds the data returned from LoadShader().

```
void Shader::CreateShaders(ID3D11Device* device)
{
    device->CreateVertexShader(m_vertex_data.ShaderCode,
        m_vertex_data.ShaderSize,
        nullptr,
        m_vertex_shader.GetAddressOf()));

    device->CreatePixelShader(m_pixel_data.ShaderCode,
        m_pixel_data.ShaderSize,
        nullptr,
        m_pixel_shader.GetAddressOf()));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep the buffer pointed to by `ShaderData::ShaderCode;` valid until you create a shader. To avoid leaks just replace it with `::std::vector< char > ShaderCode;` so the buffer will be kept safe. Actually you don't need `ShaderData` struct at all, just return a vector containing shader code.